# Problem with comparing two sql queries with EXCEPT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries. First query returns 4554 results from database and second query returns 3830 results. I need to fetch and list those 724 results that are the difference between two queries, that exist in first query and does not exist in second query. I tried with EXCEPT function, but I get error in my console

```
FOR, GROUP, HAVING, INTO expected got 'EXCEPT'
```

Any help is appreciated. Here are my queries.

```
select * from billing_trans B,members M where (sign>='2021-03-01 00:00:00' && sign<='2021-03-31 23:59:59') AND M.id=B.mid

EXCEPT

select * from billing_trans B,members M where (sign>='2021-03-01 00:00:00' && sign<='2021-03-31 23:59:59') AND M.id=B.mid
AND (trans LIKE 'BH%' OR bank IN ('SM', 'TO', 'II'));
```

Comment: Edit your question and describe what you want to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.  And learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ' I need to fetch and list those 724 results that are the difference between two queries, that exist in first query and does not exist in second query' I think it is clear.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`.  Presumably you intend:

```
select *
from dt_billing_trans B join
     dt_members M
     on M.id = B.mid
where signD >= '2021-03-01' and signD < '2021-04-01' and 
      not exists (select 1
                  from dt_billing_trans b2
                  where b2.mid = b.mid and
                        b2.signD >= '2021-03-01' and
                        b2.signD < '2021-04-01' and
                        (b2.transId LIKE 'WH%' OR b2.bank IN ('WT', 'MO', 'SL'))
                 );
```

This returns all transactions for members who do not have transactions that match the second set of conditions.

This is not exactly equivalent to your code (which does not require `except` in any database), but I suspect it is closer to what you intend.

Note:

- `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.
- Note the improved date comparisons that do not miss fractions of a second before midnight.  And the coding is much simpler.
- The SQL standard `AND` boolean operator is `AND`, not `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2 queries.
Use 1 `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dt_billing_trans B INNER JOIN dt_members M 
ON M.id = B.mid
WHERE (signD >= '2021-03-01 00:00:00' AND signD <= '2021-03-31 23:59:59') 
  AND NOT (transId LIKE 'WH%' OR bank IN ('WT', 'MO', 'SL'));
```